# How to declare a variable named 'type' in Play/Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to declare a variable with name 'type' in a Play/Scala application, since my data has this field name and I'm using JSON transforms. It just makes more sense.

Fortunately I could just rename the field, but still curious if there is a way to make the compiler ignore the type reserved word when declaring variables.

Comment: Actually I wonder if this is a problem with the parser, as it should expect a valid variable name, not a reserved word. It says "identifier expected but 'type' found]

Comment: But nothing stops you from having "type" name as DB field (if not prohibited by DB) and different variable name for the related class field.

Comment: I'm building a REST API and the incoming data is JSON. I'm using [JSON Macros](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaJsonInception) to create my model classes, so the field in the incoming JSON data must match the variable name :).. I guess I could write my own Json.Reads to handle that specific case.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
var `type` = 42
```